# Grep huge number of patterns from huge file

Tags: grep, awk, database, text

I have a file that's growing about 200,000 lines a day, and it is all formed with blocks of three lines as such:

```
1358726575123       # key
    Joseph Muller   # name
    carpenter       # job
9973834728345
    Andres Smith
    student
7836472098652
    Mariah Anthony
    dentist
```

Now, I have another file from which I extract about 10,000 key patterns, such as `1358726575123`. Then I run a `for` loop with these patterns and have to check them against the first file. If the file doesn't contain such pattern, I save the pattern in a third file for further processing:

```
for number in $(grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}' file2); do  # finds about 10.000 keys
     if ! grep -q ^$number$ file1; then           # file1 is a huge file
         printf "$number\n" >>file3               # we'll process file3 later
     fi
done
```

The example code greps a huge file 10,000 times, and I run this loop about **once a minute, during the whole day**.

Since the huge file keeps growing, what can I do to make all this faster and save some CPU? I wonder whether sorting the file somehow by its key (if so, how?) or using a db instead of plain text would help...

Comment: See this post: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer is based on the `awk` answer  posted by *potong*..
It is twice as fast as the `comm` method (on my system), for the same *6 million lines* in main-file and *10 thousand* keys... (now updated to use FNR,NR)

Although `awk` is faster than your current system, and will give you and your computer(s) some breathing space, be aware that when  data processing is as intense as you've described, you will get best overall results by switching to  a dedicated database; eg. SQlite, MySQL...

---

```
awk '{ if (/^[^0-9]/) { next }              # Skip lines which do not hold key values
       if (FNR==NR) { main[$0]=1 }          # Process keys from file "mainfile"
       else if (main[$0]==0) { keys[$0]=1 } # Process keys from file "keys"
     } END { for(key in keys) print key }' \
       "mainfile" "keys" >"keys.not-in-main"
```

---

```
# For 6 million lines in "mainfile" and 10 thousand keys in "keys"

# The awk  method
# time:
#   real    0m14.495s
#   user    0m14.457s
#   sys     0m0.044s

# The comm  method
# time:
#   real    0m27.976s
#   user    0m28.046s
#   sys     0m0.104s
```

---

Comment: This is fast, but I don't understand much of awk: what the file names should look like? I tried `file1 -> mainfile` and `file2 -> keys` with gawk and mawk, and it outputs wrong keys.

Comment: file1 has keys, names and jobs.

Comment: 'mainfile' is the big file (with keys, names and jobs). I've just called it "mainfile' because I kept getting mixed up which file was which (file1 vs file2).. 'keys' contains only the 10 thousand, or however many, keys.. For your situaton do NOT *redirect* anyting ... just use **file1 EOF file2**  They are the **names** of your files.. "EOF" is a 1-line file creadte by the script to indicate the end of the first file (main data file) and the start of teh second file (keys).  `awk` allow you to read in a series of files.. In this case that series has *3* files in it. The output goes to `stdout`

Comment: This script will print any keys which are present in `mainfile`, **AND** it will also print any keys from the `keys` file which are **NOT** in `mainfile`... That's probably what is happening...   (I'll look a bit further into it...

Comment: Thank you, @Peter.O! Since the files are confidential, I'm trying to create sample files with `$RANDOM` for uploading.

Comment: Fixed the issue with printing keys from the `keys` file which are not in `mainfile` ... see comment in script *# THIS LINE CHANGED AS PER COMMENT IN ANSWER* .. The line which follows it is the replacement.

Comment: Here is a link to my $RANDOM test data generator.... [paste.Ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/812819/)

Comment: I uploaded the files here: http://tinyurl.com/files-tar-bz2 ; keys has 5000 keys that mainfile has not.

Comment: Your test data *works fine here*... It resonded exactly as I expected... Here are *[my notes](http://paste.ubuntu.com/812891/)* on what I did and the results I got.  Maybe I've misunderstood something... if so we should go to chat, as the Stackexchange messege keeps suggesting... I'm looking more carefully at the **5000** keys you mention..

Comment: Could you please explain what `136703` means? I also get this number.

Comment: `# The first run of the script created a list of 136703 new keys..` but we only have 10000 keys to check xD

Comment: Finally! (I get 5000 keys being listed :)  .. It is twice as fast as the `comm` method for the same data on my system... Updating the answer now..

Comment: Thank you so much! It's 30 times faster than the first loop!

Comment: I wonder if a SQL database would be any faster? This awk script does wonders ;)

Comment: Assuming that you set up your SQL database with appropriate keys/indexing, it would be faster (relatively) as the data-**base** becomes larger... With flat files you always need to read every record/line sequentially.. The database will use binary-split and hash lookup searches, for only as many as there are keys you wish to read....

Answer (score 17):

The problem, of course, is that you run grep on the big file 10,000 times. You should read both files only once. If you want to stay outside scripting languages, you can do it this way:

1. Extract all numbers from file 1 and sort them
2. Extract all numbers from file 2 and sort them
3. Run `comm` on the sorted lists to get what's only on the second list

Something like this:

```
$ grep -o '^[0-9]\{12\}$' file1 | sort -u -o file1.sorted
$ grep -o  '[0-9]\{12\}'  file2 | sort -u -o file2.sorted
$ comm -13 file1.sorted file2.sorted > file3
```

See `man comm`.

If you could truncate the big file every day (like a log file) you could keep a cache of sorted numbers and wouldn't need to parse it whole every time.

Comment: Neat! 2 seconds (on not particularly fast drives) with 200,000 random lines entries in mainfile (ie. 600,000 lines) and 143,000 random keys (that's just how my test data ended up)... tested, and it works (but you knew that :) ... I do wonder about the `{12}`.. OP has used 12, but the example keys are 13 long...

Comment: Just a little note, you can do it without dealing with temporary files by using `<(grep...sort)` where the file names are.

Comment: Thank you, but grepping and sorting the files takes much longer than my previous loop (+2min.).

Comment: @Teresa e Junior. How big is your main file? ... You have mentioned that it grows at 200,000 lines a day, but not how big it is... To reduce the amount of data you nee to process, you can read just the current days' 200,000 lines by taking a note of the last line number processed (yesterday) and using `tail -n +$linenum` to output only the latest data. That way you will be processing only approximately 200,000 lines each day..   I just tested it with **6 million** lines in main-file and *10 thousand* keys... **time**: real 0m0.016s,
user 0m0.008s, sys 0m0.008s

Comment: I'm really quite puzzled/curious about how you can grep your main file **10,000** times and find it faster than this method which only greps it **once** (and once for the much smaller *file1*)...  Even if your sort takes longer than my test, I just can't get my head around the idea that reading a **big** file that many times doesn't outweigh a single sort (timewise)

Comment: @Peter.O Not so big yet, `grep | sort` takes a long time, but you had a good idea to keep sorted files for each day. Unfortunately, my example showed only 12 number keys, but it has keys of different sizes (I wrote that code for simplicity). So I don't know why, but `comm` is complaining the files are not sorted and is outputting crap... (I tried `sort` with and without `-n`).

Comment: If you have no whitespace or comments on lines which hold a key, then you don't need to *grep* your key-file at all; just *sort* it as-is... As for the main-file's *grep* pattern, just change it to `^[0-9]\+$` (if it has no white-space or comments, otherwise you could use `sed` )

Comment: @TeresaeJunior: `comm` complaining is just because of `sort -n`. The numeric sort is unnecessary, I'll update the answer. [edit: oops, you tested that. Then I don't know. Why don't you put the real specifications?] Regarding speed, on a 2.5 GB file1 I found this method takes ~10% the time than performing 10,000 `grep -q`s (which is very fast, but not so much).

Comment: You might want to compare the speed with `--line-regexp '[0-9]\{12\}'` for the first file.

Comment: Fastest performance will most often result from using the tool(s) you know best.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, definitely do use a database. They're made exactly for tasks like this.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have much experience with databases. Which database do you recommend? I've got MySQL and the sqlite3 command installed.

Comment: They are both fine for this, sqlite is simpler because it's basically just a file and an SQL API to access it. With MySQL you need to set up a MySQL server in order to use it. While that's not very difficult either, sqlite might be best to start with.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
 awk '/^[0-9]/{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]==1)print x}' file{1,2} >file3
```

EDIT:

Amended script to allow for duplicates and unknown keys in both files, still produces keys from the first file not present in the second:

```
 awk '/^[0-9]/{if(FNR==NR){a[$0]=1;next};if($0 in a){a[$0]=2}}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]==1)print x}' file{1,2} >file3
```

Comment: This will miss new keys which occur more than once in the main file (and for that matter, which occurr more than once in the keys file) It seems to require that the array count incrementing of the main file is not alowed to exceed 1, or some equivalent workaround (+1 because it is pretty close to the mark)

Comment: I tried with gawk and mawk, and it outputs wrong keys...

Comment: @Peter.O I assumed the main file had unique keys and that file 2 was a subset of the main file.

Comment: @potong The second one works good and very fast! Thank you!

Comment: *@Teresa e Junior* Are you sure it is working correctly yet?.. Using the [test data you provided](http://tinyurl.com/files-tar-bz2), which should output **5000** keys, when I run it, it produces **136703** keys, just as I got until I finally understood what your requirements were... *@potong* Of course! *FNR==NR* (I've never used it before :)

Comment: @Peter.O The first command has that problem, the second works good.

Answer (score 2):

With that much data, you should really switch to a database. In the meantime, one thing you must do to get anywhere near decent performance is not to search `file1` separately for each key. Run a single `grep` to extract all the non-excluded keys at once. Since that `grep` also returns lines that don't contain a key, filter those away.

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}' file2 |
grep -Fxv -f - file1 |
grep -vx '[0-9]\{12\}' >file3
```

(`-Fx` means to search whole lines, literally. `-f -` means to read a list of patterns from standard input.)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't address the problem of storing keys that aren't in the big file, it will store the keys that are in it.

Comment: @Kevin exactly, and this has forced me to use the loop.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior: adding `-v` (`-Fxv`) may take care of that.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That would pick all the lines in the big file that don't match any in the key file, including names, jobs, etc.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I'd misread the question. I've added a filter for non-key lines, though my preference now goes to [using `comm`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29624/grep-huge-number-of-patterns-from-huge-file/29641#29641).

Answer (score 2):

Permit me to reinforce what others have said, "Get thee to a database!"

There are [MySQL binaries freely available for most platforms.](http://www.MySQL.com/downloads/)

Why not SQLite? It's memory-based, loading a flat-file when you start it, then closing it when you're done. This means that if your computer crashes or the SQLite process goes away, so does all the data.

Your problem looks like just a couple lines of SQL, and will run in milliseconds!

After installing MySQL (which I recommend over other choices), I'd shell out $40 for O'Reilly's [*SQL Cookbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009763) by Anthony Molinaro, which has lots of problem patterns, starting with simple `SELECT * FROM table` queries, and going through aggregates and multiple joins.

Comment: Yes, I'll start migrating my data to SQL in a few days, thank you! The awk scripts have been helping me a lot until I get it all done, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the exact output that you are looking for, but probably the easiest way is:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}' file2 | sed 's/.*/^&$/' > /tmp/numpatterns.grep
grep -vf /tmp/numpatterns.grep file1 > file3
rm -f /tmp/numpatterns.grep
```

You could also use:

```
sed -ne '/.*\([0-9]\{12\}.*/^\1$/p' file2 > /tmp/numpatterns.grep
grep -vf /tmp/numpatterns.grep file1 > file3
rm -f /tmp/numpatterns.grep
```

Each of these creates a temporary pattern file which is used to glean out the numbers from the large file (`file1`).

Comment: I believe this too finds numbers that are in the big file, not those that aren't.

Comment: Correct, I didn't see the '!' in the OP.  Just need to use  `grep -vf` instead of `grep -f`.

Comment: No @arcege, grep -vf won't display keys not matched, it will display everything including names and jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with you getting a database (MySQL is fairly easy to use). Until you get that running, I like Angus's `comm` solution, but so many people are trying with `grep` and getting it wrong that I thought I'd show the (or at least one) correct way to do it with `grep`.

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}' keyfile | grep -v -f <(grep -o '^[0-9]\{12\}' bigfile)
```

The first `grep` gets the keys. The third `grep` (in the `<(...)`) takes all the keys used in the big file, and the `<(...)` passes it like a file as an argument to `-f` in the second grep.  That causes the second `grep` to use it as a list of lines to match.  It then uses this to match its input (the list of keys) from the pipe (first `grep`),  and prints any keys extracted from the key file and not (`-v`) the big file.

Of course you can do this with temporary files you have to keep track of and remember to delete:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}'  keyfile >allkeys
grep -o '^[0-9]\{12\}' bigfile >usedkeys
grep -v -f usedkeys allkeys
```

This prints all lines in `allkeys` that don't appear in `usedkeys`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is *slow*, and I get a memory error after 40 seconds: `grep: Memory exhausted`

Comment: @Peter.O But it's correct. Anyway, that's why I'd suggest a database or `comm`, in that order.

Comment: Yes that works, but is much slower than the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The keyfile does not change? Then you should avoid searching the old entries again and again.

With `tail -f` you can get the output of a growing file.

```
tail -f growingfile | grep -f keyfile
```

grep -f reads the patterns from a file, one line as a pattern.

Comment: That would be good, but the key file is always different.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't going to post my answer because I thought that such amount of data shouldn't be processed with a shell script, and the right answer to use a database was already given. But since now there are 7 other approaches...

Reads the first file in memory, then greps the second file for numbers and checks if values are stored in memory. It should be faster than multiple `grep`s, if you have enough memory to load the whole file, that is.

```
declare -a record
while read key
do
    read name
    read job
    record[$key]="$name:$job"
done < file1

for number in $(grep -o '[0-9]\{12\}' file2)
do
    [[ -n ${mylist[$number]} ]] || echo $number >> file3
done
```

Comment: I've got enough memory, but I found this one even slower. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@jan-steinman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29993/11052) that you should use a database for this kind of task. There are lots of ways to hack together a solution with a shell script as the other answers show, but doing it that way will lead to a lot of misery if you're going to use and maintain the code for any length of time more than just a one-day throw-away project.

Assuming you're on a Linux box then you most likely have Python installed by default which includes the [sqlite3 library](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) as of Python v2.5. You can check your Python version with:

```
% python -V
Python 2.7.2+
```

I recommend using [sqlite3 library](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) because it is a simple file-based solution that exists for all platforms (including inside your web browser!) and it does not require a server to be installed. Essentially zero-configuration and zero-maintenance.

Below is a simple python script that will parse the file format that you gave as an example and then does a simple "select all" query and outputs everything it stored in the db.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3
import sys

dbname = '/tmp/simple.db'
filename = '/tmp/input.txt'
with sqlite3.connect(dbname) as conn:
    conn.execute('''create table if not exists people (key integer primary key, name text, job text)''')
    with open(filename) as f:
        for key in f:
            key = key.strip()
            name = f.next().strip()
            job = f.next().strip()
            try:
                conn.execute('''insert into people values (?,?,?)''', (key, name, job))
            except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
                sys.stderr.write('record already exists: %s, %s, %s\n' % (key, name, job))
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # get all people
    cur.execute('''select * from people''')
    for row in cur:
        print row

    # get just two specific people
    person_list = [1358726575123, 9973834728345]
    cur.execute('''select * from people where key in (?,?)''', person_list)
    for row in cur:
        print row

    # a more general way to get however many people are in the list
    person_list = [1358726575123, 9973834728345]
    template = ','.join(['?'] * len(person_list))
    cur.execute('''select * from people where key in (%s)''' % (template), person_list)
    for row in cur:
        print row
```

Yes, this means that you'll need to [learn some SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp), but it will be well worth it in the long run. Also, instead of parsing your log files, maybe you could write data directly to your sqlite database.

Comment: Thank you for the python script! I think `/usr/bin/sqlite3` works the same way for shell scripts (http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sqlite3), though I've never used it.

Comment: Yes, you can use `/usr/bin/sqlite3` with shell scripts, however I recommend avoiding shell scripts except for simple throw-away programs and instead use a language like python which has better error handling and is easier to maintain and grow.