# check patterns that don't exist in sqlite

Tags: shell, performance, efficiency, sql, sqlite

I explained a similar situation with plain text files on [Grep huge number of patterns from huge file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29624/grep-huge-number-of-patterns-from-huge-file/30144). Many people there said I should, so now I'm migrating my data to a sqlite database:

I have a file from which I extract about 10,000 patterns. Then I check if the database doesn't contain such patterns. If it doesn't, I need to save them externally in `file` for further processing:

```
for id in $(grep ^[0-9] keys); do
  if [[ -z $(sqlite3 db.sqlite "select id from main where id = $id") ]]; then
    echo $id >>file
  fi
done
```

Since I'm new to SQL, I couldn't find a simple way to do this. Also, this loop is useless as it is 20 times slower than what I achieved with `awk` on the mentioned URL.

Since the database is huge, keeps growing, and I run this loop very frequently, is it possible to make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pattern, you're invoking a new instance of the `sqlite` program which connects to the database anew. That's a waste. You should build a single query that looks for any of the keys, then execute that one query. Database clients are good at executing large queries.

If the matching lines in the `keys` file only contain digits, then you can build the query as follows:

```
{
  echo 'select id from main where id in (';
  <keys grep -x '[0-9][0-9]*' |     # retain only lines containing only digits
  sed -e '1! s/^/, /' |             # add ", " at the beginning of every line except the first
  echo ');'
} | sqlite3 db.sqlite
```

For more general input data, you get the idea: use text transformations to build a single large query. Be careful to [validate your input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection); here we make sure that what gets injected into the query is syntactically valid. There's actually a corner case in the example above: if there is no match in the file, then the SQL syntax is invalid; if that might happen, you'll need to treat this case specially. Here's more complex code that takes care of the empty case:

```
<keys grep -x '[0-9][0-9]*' |
if read first; then {
    echo 'select id from main where id in (' "$first"
    sed -e 's/^/, /'
    echo ');'
  } | sqlite3 db.sqlite
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you really replace the `if` with a list.  Actually I would even replace the `[[]]`s with `[]`s, and then run in `dash` or other lighter `sh`.  This even seems simple enough to ditch the entire `for`, and run with `xargs` (always my preference, better performance) So for example, maybe something like this ...

```
grep ^[0-9] keys | xargs -P0 -I '{id}' \
sh -c '[ -z "$(sqlite3 db.sqlite =\"select id from main where id = '{id}'\")" ] && \
echo '{id}' >> file'
```

My escaping is most likely off, but this should point you in the right direction.
I would suspect this would perform MUCH faster, least because you would be running parallel via `-P`.

If for some reason even this is crawling, you could always look into something that dumps the sqlite db.  You would likely be writing a script, if you took that approach.  I would only consider it, if it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Import your IDs into some new table, then use that table to query your `main` table. Drop the table whet you're done with it.

```bash
{ echo id; grep '^[0-9]' keys; } |
sqlite3 database.db \
    'CREATE TABLE ids ( id INTEGER UNIQUE )' \
    '.import /dev/stdin ids' \
    'SELECT * FROM main NATURAL JOIN ids' \
    'DROP TABLE ids'
```

Testing:

```
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT * FROM main;
┌────┬─────────────────┐
│ id │      word       │
├────┼─────────────────┤
│ 1  │ concessionaire  │
│ 2  │ goniometrically │
│ 3  │ meshed          │
│ 4  │ Celtic          │
│ 5  │ guiltless       │
│ 6  │ sclerodactylia  │
│ 7  │ spiritism       │
│ 8  │ ratchel         │
│ 9  │ Bajau           │
│ 10 │ semimineral     │
└────┴─────────────────┘
```

```bash
$ cat keys
3
7
78
190
```

Running the given command would output the following (select `id` instead of `*` to only output the IDs):

```
3|meshed
7|spiritism
```